# Cambiar texto que esta dentro del span que esta sin id ni class

Tags: html

```
<div id="et-secondary-menu">
    <ul id="et-secondary-nav" class="menu">
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-1405">
        <a href="https://handcraftedchile.com/mi-cuenta/">Mi cuenta</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1407"><a href="https://handcraftedchile.com/carro/">Carrito</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1406"><a href="https://handcraftedchile.com/finalizar-comprar/">Verifica tu compra y selecciona medio de pago</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1444"><a href="https://handcraftedchile.com/contacto/">Contacto</a></li>
    </ul>
    <a href="https://handcraftedchile.com/carro/" class="et-cart-info">
        <span>0 elementos</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que el nombre de la clase *et-cart-info* sea única sería algo así. De lo contrario, te recomendaría añadirle un id.

Este ejemplo es utilizando javascript puro, en el caso de que no utilices jQuery.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('et-cart-info')[0].firstElementChild.innerHTML = 'NuevoTexto';
```

```html
<div id="et-secondary-menu">
    <ul id="et-secondary-nav" class="menu">
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-1405">
        <a href="https://handcraftedchile.com/mi-cuenta/">Mi cuenta</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1407"><a href="https://handcraftedchile.com/carro/">Carrito</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1406"><a href="https://handcraftedchile.com/finalizar-comprar/">Verifica tu compra y selecciona medio de pago</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1444"><a href="https://handcraftedchile.com/contacto/">Contacto</a></li>
    </ul>
    <a href="https://handcraftedchile.com/carro/" class="et-cart-info">
        <span>0 elementos</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias funciona perfectamente, en el caso de los elementos hijos, como añado un clase para ese span?. se como hacerlo con el div directo, pero en hijos no se como va.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien a que te refieres. ¿Quieres decir algo como esto? <span class='myClass'>0 elementos</span>

Answer (score 1):

Si tu html tiene esta estructura es fácil, usa [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), copia mi ejemplo:

```js
$("#et-secondary-menu span").text("Escribe lo que quieras");
document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerText = "Escribe otra vez.";
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="et-secondary-menu">
    <ul id="et-secondary-nav" class="menu">
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-1405">
        <a href="https://handcraftedchile.com/mi-cuenta/">Mi cuenta</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1407"><a href="https://handcraftedchile.com/carro/">Carrito</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1406"><a href="https://handcraftedchile.com/finalizar-comprar/">Verifica tu compra y selecciona medio de pago</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1444"><a href="https://handcraftedchile.com/contacto/">Contacto</a></li>
    </ul>
    <a href="https://handcraftedchile.com/carro/" class="et-cart-info">
        <span>0 elementos</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: en caso de que no sea jquery y sea con un javascript puro?.

Comment: He editado la respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo utilizando [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) y cambiando su [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

```js
document.querySelector('.et-cart-info span').innerHTML = '1 elemento';
```

```html
<div id="et-secondary-menu">
  <ul id="et-secondary-nav" class="menu">
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-1405">
      <a href="https://handcraftedchile.com/mi-cuenta/">Mi cuenta</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1407"><a href="https://handcraftedchile.com/carro/">Carrito</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1406"><a href="https://handcraftedchile.com/finalizar-comprar/">Verifica tu compra y selecciona medio de pago</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1444"><a href="https://handcraftedchile.com/contacto/">Contacto</a></li>
  </ul>
  <a href="https://handcraftedchile.com/carro/" class="et-cart-info">
    <span>0 elementos</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.js"
    integrity="sha256-fNXJFIlca05BIO2Y5zh1xrShK3ME+/lYZ0j+ChxX2DA="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script>

  $(document).ready(function(){

    // llamada a la función que carga el texto en el span

    // cambiaTextoAlSpan("hola desde jq");
    cambiaTextoAlSpan("hola desde js");

  });

  /**
    * Función que asigna el texto en el span
   */

  function cambiaTextoAlSpan(texto_nuevo){

   //con jquery $("#et-secondary-menu>a>span").html(texto_nuevo);
   //con js solo si el html es estático
   var padre = document.getElementById('et-secondary-menu');
   var a_x = padre.childNodes[3];
   var span_x = a_x.childNodes[1];
    //usa .nodeValue para ie y textContent para otros navegadores
    span_x.textContent=texto_nuevo;



  }


    </script>


</head>
<body>



  <div id="et-secondary-menu">
      <ul id="et-secondary-nav" class="menu">
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-1405">
          <a href="https://handcraftedchile.com/mi-cuenta/">Mi cuenta</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1407"><a href="https://handcraftedchile.com/carro/">Carrito</a></li>
              <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1406"><a href="https://handcraftedchile.com/finalizar-comprar/">Verifica tu compra y selecciona medio de pago</a></li>
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1444"><a href="https://handcraftedchile.com/contacto/">Contacto</a></li>
      </ul>
      <a href="https://handcraftedchile.com/carro/" class="et-cart-info">
          <span>0 elementos</span>
      </a>
  </div>




</body>
```

Comment: Hola! Gracias por tu aporte. Considera agregar una explicación, a veces las respuestas que son solo código no son bien recibidas por la comunidad.

Comment: te dejo la versión jq y la versión js, saludos

Comment: gracias.. me gusta trabajar mas con javascript puro.. pero esta muy bueno el de jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Por si te sirve de algo, esto cambia desde el IFRAME a la página principal. Es decir, en el Iframe insertamos este Script, que modifica los elementos el el primer span de la página primaria.

```
<script>
    window.parent.document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerText = 'Tramitación SAT smartGyro';
</script>
```

Obviamente el span ha de estar en el HTML principal.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hola Chema,  bienvenido y gracias por tu colaboración, aunque debo decirte que tu respuesta no parece tener nada que ver con la pregunta, te sugiero que leas atentamente la pregunta y luego edites tu respuesta para adaptara a la misma, de esa forma, evitarás recibir votos negativos, ver [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.